# CSRF protection for file upload posts

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, multipartform-data, csrf-protection

I have an angularJS application in which I use [Angular's CSRF protection mechanism](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) for all POST, PUT and other nonsafe web service calls. It works well except for one case: a multipart/form-data POST which uploads a file to the server.

In this case, as I am posting a form and file data directly to the web service, the angular $http service is not involved, and therefore does not append the CSRF header to the request in the way that it does with XHR requests.

I have a couple of questions:

- do I need to protect this POST against CSRF (I imagine I do)
- can I / how can I get Angular to add the CSRF header to the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided in the end that as the post was made by a form rather than AJAX, the method should have been in a standard MVC controller rather that a WebAPI one. That way I could use the standard MVC `Html.AntiForgeryToken` helper on the form and the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you uploads a file to the server by means of XHR through jQuery, you can add default header:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "requestVerificationToken": myToken
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes. I can do the same using angular's $http service as well, but I'm using an angular component called ngUpload which uses a form post (inside an IFrame, I believe).

Comment: ngUpload have option ["upload-options-enable-rails-csrf"](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload) . It turns on support CSRF by adding a hidden form field with the csrf token.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that was the approach used with that option. It might work. Will investigate.